# Need help inserting text AFTER two consecutive matches using sed on macOS

Tags: macos, sed, zsh

How do I insert text after two consecutive matches in a file using sed. Is this possible? If it is, how do I do the following?

My file:

```
abcdef()K
.xyz 1
('I want to add text here')
```

Note that the .xyz will be same but it can be 1 or 2 or 3 or any other number. But .xyz WILL DEFINIETLY BE under abcdef()K. I want to add text exactly AFTER the .xyz part.

Please do help guys. Thanks.

Comment: `perl -0777 -pE 's/^(abcdef\(\)\R\.xyz.*\R?)/\1(your text here)\n/mg' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this perl:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/^(abcdef\(\)K\R\.xyz.*\R?)/\1(your text here)\n/mg' file
```

Or this awk:

```
awk -v ins="(your text)" '/abcdef()K/{f=1; print; next}
f && /\.xyz.*/{f=0; print; print ins; next}
{f=0; print}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If `.xyz [0-9]` is constant and is always on the line below the first match, then you can append the new line with `sed`

```
$ sed '/\.xyz [0-9]*/a New Text' input_file
abcdef()K
.xyz 1
New Text
```

Otherwise, you can match the first line, add a condition to substitute the match on  the second line if the first matched, substitute it for itself, jump to new line and append the new text.

```
sed '/a.*()K/ {N;s/\.xyz [0-9]*/&\nNew Text/}' input_file
abcdef()K
.xyz 1
New Text
```

Comment: Can I do this on mac sir? sed on mac demands you add a\ and add text in next line. And this finds the match only of .xyz <number> sir. I want abcdef()K to be matched as well.

Comment: @Mtoklitz113 The first command where we append should work. The second may not due to the new line, you can try `sed '/a.*()K/ {N;s/\.xyz [0-9]*/&'$'\nNew Text/}'` instead or `sed '/a.*()K/ {N;s/\.xyz [0-9]*/&\\\nNew Text/}'`

Comment: I'm a getting 'bad flag in substitute command' error sir on using the second option.

Comment: @Mtoklitz113 My commands are tested on GNU sed, i cannot replicate your bad flag issue. Do you have gsed on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/abcdef()K/!b' -e ':a;n;/\.xyz/!ba' -e 'a new text added' file
```

If a line does not contain `abcdef()K` bail out.

Print the current line and fetch the next.

If the current line does not contain `.xyz`, repeat above.

Otherwise, append `new text added` to the current line.

---

```
sed -e '/abcdef()K/!b' -e ':a' -e 'n' -e '/\.xyz/!ba' -e 'a new text added' file
```

Or:

```
cat <<\! | sed -f - file
/abcdef()K/!b
:a
n
/\.xyz/!ba
a new text added
!
```

Comment: I use a mac sir. Does it work on a mac?

Comment: @Mtoklitz113 I believe so but you may need to break it out another 2 steps, see edit.

Comment: I'm getting the error sed: -e: No such file or directory sir. What do I do?

Comment: @Mtoklitz113 you can put the commands in a file or use the second alternative.

Comment: potong's sed requires GNU sed. Mac only has bsd sed installed. You can install GNU sed with brew or macports.

Comment: This makes the replacement with `abcdef()K\n\n.xyz 2` (ie with a blank line between the two patterns...)

Comment: What's the 2 in abcdef()K\n\n.xyz 2 @dawg?

Comment: *What's the 2 in abcdef()K\n\n.xyz 2* The `2` is just any digit. Just showing that this `sed` will match with a blank line between the two lines.